# Sha256 output length makes no sense to me

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha

I've just played around with SHA256, and I've noticed something weird: the length of the hexdigest is 32 chars, each can be one of 16 different characters (0-9, a-f). Now correct me if I'm wrong, but this is not 256. 16*32 makes 512.
So... what am I missing here? Why the extra 16 letters?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are wrongly multiplying 32*16, you should multiply 32*4=128 since a hex is 4-bit. Where did you see that SHA-256 hash 32 hex output?

Comment: Yep, the output is 256 bits / 32 bytes, so the hex digest is not too long, it's 32 characters short (2 hex characters for each byte).

Comment: @kelalaka first of all, you are right of course. It just make the problem bigger. The thing it, I'm not sure it doesn't make the hole ever bigger: 64*16 is 1024. If I wanted a 2^256 problem to solve, I only need 16 chars.
The thing is I'm kinda confused again, as I know that 1 hex char is 4 bits. And you are right, 4 * 64 is 256. So... why the number of possible outcomes if not not 2^256? I'm not sure this is the place to ask this, but I'll try and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not really my answer, it was @kelaka that set me stright on the path to an answer in the comment - so I'm not getting to excited about myself.

I was trying to calculate the number of options wrong, but multiplying 16 and 64 (the real length of a hash). If I calculated it the way it should have been - 16 ^ 64, I'd get a large number that is equal to 2^256, as can be seen in this code here:

```
>>> 16**64 == 2**256
True
```

Sorry for wasting everyone's time on me being stupid.